# Laravel model form binding not working for edit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a controller `TourCategoryController.php` and has edit method:

```
public function edit(TCategory $tCategory)
{
    return view('admin.manage.tour.category.edit')->withCategory($tCategory);
}
```

And below is the code from my view `edit`:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    {{Form::model($category,['route' => ['tour-category.update', $category->id ], 'method' => "PUT"]) }}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

The trouble I'm having is, the input field is not being filled with form modal binding.

While inspecting the edit form action attribute shows `action="http://localhost:8000/manage/tour-category"` while it should be like `action="http://localhost:8000/manage/tour-category/{id}"`

Route for the controller:

```
Route::prefix('manage')
->middleware('role:superadministrator|administrator|user')
->group(function () {
         Route::resource('tour-category','TourCategoryController');
});
```

Comment: Show us your routes also!

Comment: use laravel form for  form model binding , laravel foem model  bindig does not works in html  form

Comment: Tried model binding wiht HTML collective. Same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using `Form Facades`

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('tour-category.update', $category->id) }}">
        {{ method_field('PUT') }}
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use laravel text field instead of plain form text field.

```
 {{ Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'name']) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
{{ Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'name']) }}
```

instead of

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
```